# How to loop through an array of object nth number of time so that it loop over all the child array of object if exist

Tags: javascript

How to loop through an array of object nth number of time so that it loop over all the child array of object if exist and get it's Id in order.

```
let = [{
  "id": "1",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "child": [
           {
            "id": "1234"
           }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "child": [
        {

          "id": "42",
          "child": [
            {

              "id": "43"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[1,12,123,1234,2,22,3,4,42,43]
```

My try, It's not working and not getting any logic.

```
result.reduce((pv, cv) => {
  console.log(cv)

  let temp = cv
  let arr = []
  if(temp.hasOwnProperty("split")){
    arr = temp.split
    pv.push(temp.id)
    // again arr should loop, I'm still finding some logic!
  }
  return pv
}, [])
```

Kindly give some logical steps even if you won't like to answer. I'll try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive function with a persistent variable pointing to the array. `.reduce` isn't really the right approach here, and your test of `temp.split` doesn't make any sense - the two properties in question are `id` and `child`. Unconditionally push the ID (not inside the `if`), and if the child array exists, call the recursive function on it.

```js
const input=[{id:"1",child:[{id:"12",child:[{id:"123",child:[{id:"1234"}]}]},{id:"2",child:[{id:"22"}]},{id:"3"},{id:"4",child:[{id:"42",child:[{id:"43"}]}]}]}];

const getAllChildIds = (arr, ids = []) => {
  for (const { id, child } of arr) {
    ids.push(Number(id));
    if (child) getAllChildIds(child, ids);
  }
  return ids;
};
console.log(getAllChildIds(input));
```